# How to add control to items statically

Tags: sapui5

Sometimes in an aggregation binding, I need to add some controls to the generated list of items statically. Is there some elegant solution for this?

Let's say I have a Select with the following code:

```xml
<Select width="100%"
  items="{project>/Milestones}"
  selectedKey="0"
>
  <core:Item
    key="{project>Id}"
    text="{project>Name}"
  />
</Select>
```

Bound to a model with these data:

```json
{
  Milestones: [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Cost Estimation 1",
      "Description": "Initial cost estimation"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Pid Packages",
      "Description": "Ready for RFQs"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to add an item to the Select with `key="0"` and `value="< Blank >"` and have that stay there even when the content of `project>/Milestones` is changed, but I don't want to add it to the actual aggregation.

The solutions that I have at the moment seem really hackish and create problems later on: creating a new model (property) leads to having the data duplicated in multiple lists and therefor it will probably get out of sync at some point. I've also tried adding the static items through binding events, but this is somewhat error prone and very verbose.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to bind one list to two different collections on different models? Or you just have one collection and you want to insert manually some items in the list?

Comment: I edited the question and left only the part about adding a static item to the aggregation.

Comment: Ok! I will give you a snippet once at home. In the meantime, could you provide a bit of code? Your XML view, to know which controls you are using, the part of the model are bindinding, to know the data structure, and one example of the 'static element you want to insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here the promised snippet. First of all, if you just want to add a "blank" item, I recommend you to use ComboBox instead of Select, because you can always delete your selection. I added it to the snippet as well.
But if you want to add an item, you just need to use the `addItem()` function described [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Select/methods/addItem)

I also added a button to modify your model, so you can see how the '< Blank >' item remains there even when you change it.

#### Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m' data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
      <Title text="With Select" class="sapUiMediumMarginTop"></Title>
      <Select id="mySelect" width="100%" items="{ path: 'project>/Milestones', events:{ change: '.onSelectBindingChange' }, templateShareable: false}" selectedKey="0">
        <core:Item key="{project>Id}" text="{project>Name}" />
      </Select>
      <Title text="With ComboBox" class="sapUiMediumMarginTop"></Title>
      <ComboBox width="100%" items="{ path: 'project>/Milestones', templateShareable: false}" selectedKey="0">
        <core:Item key="{project>Id}" text="{project>Name}" />
      </ComboBox>
      <Button text="Modify Model" press="onButtonPressed" class="sapUiLargeMarginTop sapUiLargeMarginBottom"></Button>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>


  <script>
    // define a new (simple) Controller type
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
      onSelectBindingChange: function(oEvent) {
        var oNewItem = new sap.ui.core.Item({
          key: 0,
          text: "< Blank >"
        });
        this.getView().byId("mySelect").addItem(oNewItem);
      },

      onButtonPressed: function(oEvent) {
        var aMilestones = this.getView().getModel("project").getProperty("/Milestones");
        aMilestones.push({
          Id: 4,
          Name: "New Milestone",
          Description: "Just a model modification"
        });
        this.getView().getModel("project").setProperty("/Milestones", aMilestones);
      }
    });



    /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
    // create some dummy JSON data
    var data = {
      Milestones: [{
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Cost Estimation 1",
          "Description": "Initial cost estimation",
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Pid Packages",
          "Description": "Ready for RFQs",
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Certificate Check",
          "Description": null,
        }
      ]
    };
    var oJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oJSONModel.setData(data);

    // instantiate the View
    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({
      viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
    myView.setModel(oJSONModel, "project");
    // put the View onto the screen
    myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>

</head>

<body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
</body>

</html>
```